# Extract a string from an XML file? (Using TBXML)

Tags: objective-c, xml, dom

No trouble reading and loading, but I'm not sure about the syntax to grab a string from a particular location.

For example, with this XML...

```
<stories>
  <story ID="01" name="Story 1">
    <scenes>
      <scene ID="01" name="Scene 1">
        <pages>
          <page ID="01">
            <charName>
              n010101
            </charName>
            <charTalk>
              s010101
            </charTalk>
          </page>
        </pages>
      </scene>
    </scenes>
  </story>
</stories>
```

How would I say...
"from charName in page with ID 01 in pages in scene with ID 01 in scenes in story with ID 01 in stories"

As a path, it would be something like:
`stories > story 01 > scenes > scene 01 > pages > page 01 > charName`

I've looked at other projects that implement TBXML, but I can't find what I'm looking for.
(I'm also really bad at looking through others' source code, so I've probably come across it more than once.)

[My **loadStories** method on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/KQnQVQDD)

Edit: I wonder... Which is faster, TBXML or a plist, and which is easier to code for?
They're both loaded fully into memory, so it comes down to line count, readability, and parse time.

...
Still waiting on an answer. I don't mind switching to NSXMLParser if someone can throw a good (useful) tutorial at me, but TBXML is much lighter, even if it does have a slightly larger footprint with huge files.
How much does it take for TBXML to become heavy, anyway?

Comment: Are you looking for a key path like functionality?

Comment: @Deepak "key path"? What's that?

Comment: I thought you wanted some kind of quick access method where you would pass `stories.story[id='01`].scenes.scene[id='01'].pages.page[id='01'].charName` and get the value.

Comment: @Deepak Yes, something like that. I'll need to tweak some things to make it work, but I don't know where to begin. Rereading `-loadStories` is a start, I guess...

Comment: XPath would make this really easy, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML has a ridiculous amount of overhead, which can get horribly inefficient in no time at all.

Property lists are easy enough to deal with, and it's not hard to convert the contents to raw data.
NSJSON is not the absolute fastest, but it supports ARC and is much simpler to implement.

---

Yes, I know I didn't actually solve the problem. This answer is for an easier, significantly better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the document as a string and TBXML doesn't support it.  I ended up adding a property to the TBXML class **xmlString** and storing the string read from the URL.

```
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL*)aURL 
{
    self.xmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:aURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    self = [self initWithXMLString:self.xmlString];
    if (self != nil) {
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, TBXML does not have API for doing what you want to do. You will have to code the navigation of the XML tree yourself. If you only have one or two types of queries, this shouldn't be too terrible. `libxml` does support XPath, so you might consider using that instead if you need to perform a variety of different kinds of queries on the XML at run time.

Since you're already loading all the stories from XML into model objects, though, you will likely find it easier and faster to work with the model objects and only save and load from XML. This also lets you dispose of the parsed XML data aside from what your model needs at runtime, rather than keeping two different representations indefinitely.

As for plists versus XML: Provided you use plist-friendly data types, loading and saving with a plist is much simpler, since all that revivification work you did is done for you. But since you are using model classes rather than raw `NSArray`/`NSDictionary` collections, you likely won't see much benefit over using TBXML.

One thing that would simplify your code is to have objects know how to build themselves given the appropriate TBXML object. Instead of a massive `loadStories` method that knows everything about the entire data hierarchy, you would load the XML document and pass it to a Story initializer, which will, to initialize its scenes, pass the document (and the appropriate parent element) to a Scene initializer, which will take care of building its children, and on down the line. Each class then worries about making sure that it's initialized, and changes to the hierarchy end up localized within a single class rather than in these god-methods.

Comment: I kinda figured it would be a bit of a task to turn this into something usable. While I work on that, though, would it be possible to use the current implementation as-is? I want to have a working (albeit inefficient) implementation so there's a clear goal, rather than just "something that does what I want". (Comparing A to B is easier than comparing A to 1, you know?)

Comment: @Thromordyn TBXML can navigate the XML tree, so you can do whatever you want with it. You will be writing your own "walk through the children of the root till I find the Story with the matching ID, grab that Story, now walk through its children till I find the Scene with the ID I want, okay, now grab that Scene and…" It will likely be cleaner if you break it into methods like `-sceneWithID:` and `-storyWithID:`. If you want to work directly with the XML, you might need something more like `-sceneWithID:parentElement:`.

Comment: What I meant to imply is that I'm not sure exactly how to say "search for A, then search for B in A, etc" in code. Eh, I'll just go for the better option first. // A new class with a super creative name to hold the methods for retrieving specific charName and charTalk values... I'll see what I can do.